# Unable to Enter text into textbox

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am trying to automate FeeCRM Website. After login to Application click on **Forms->New Form** , there i am not able to enter text into Title field because of Xpath issue, i have used frames also. still im not able to find the issue. Plz help me with code.
**Url**: https://www.freecrm.com/index.html
**My Code**:

```
driver.get("https://www.freecrm.com/index.html");
driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("XXXXX");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("XXXXX");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='btn btn-small']")).click();
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
driver.switchTo().frame("mainpanel");
WebElement Form=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='navmenu']/ul/li[14]"));
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(Form).build().perform();
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul//li[14]//li[1]")).click();
String FormName=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='New Form']")).getText();
System.out.println(FormName);
Assertion.assertEquals(FormName,"New Form");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='New Form']")).click();
WebDriverWait w=new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
//driver.switchTo().frame("mainpanel");
//String F1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//fieldset[@class='fieldset']")).getText();
//  Assertion.assertEquals(F1,"Feedback form");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='feedbackForm']//table//tr[1]//td[2]//input")).sendKeys("Enter Form Name");
```

Comment: Could you please provide relevant HTML?

Answer (score 0):

My advise urgently improve your code style, locators...
Maybe will be better to use some frameworks, try Selenide http://selenide.org/

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("XXXXX");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("XXXXX");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[value='Login']"))).click();

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.name("mainpanel")));

new Actions(driver)
        .moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title='Forms']")))
        .build().perform();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title='New Form']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.id("title")).sendKeys("my title");
```

Comment: Thank u, this line is not working for me. driver.findElement(By.id("title")).sendKeys("my title");  Error is:Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"title"}

Comment: I tested and it’s work. Put wait before title to be sure